# How to save a private (not anonymous) class in ormlite

Tags: java, android, orm, ormlite

I have a file that contains a main `public class SubjectTree` and a private `class Learning group`.

Like this:

```
public class SubjectTree {
...
}
class LearningGroup {
...
}
```

Is there a way to store the Learning group class in a separate database table referencing Subject tree using `ormlite` ?

Comment: Hrm.  And I assume pulling the class out into it's own file isn't an option.  Does `LearningGroup` have a visible constructor?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Gray no, it does not have a visible constructor. I am not getting an error, but I can't use it in the Databasehelper with the `TableUtils.createTable(..)`